# What is the easiest way to obtain the confusion matrix from python CRFSuite?

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix, crf, python-crfsuite

I am trying to obtain the confusion matrix from [python CRFsuite](https://python-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

This my code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_y, normalize='true', labels=lables)
```

error:

```
ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.
```

I tried to use `MultiLabelBinarizer()`, but still couldn't get the confusion matrix.

After googling around I found this [answer](https://gitmemory.com/issue/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite/49/626024147), it says that for the confusion matrix function you have to flatten the `y_test` and `pred_y`. I took a look at the source code of CRFsuite for other metrics [here](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn_crfsuite/metrics.html), they do use a fallaten function:

```
def _flattens_y(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(y_true, y_pred, *args, **kwargs):
        y_true_flat = flatten(y_true)
        y_pred_flat = flatten(y_pred)
        return func(y_true_flat, y_pred_flat, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

But there is no function for obtaining the `confusion matrix`.

The `y_test` and `pred_y` are nested lists.

How can I flatten the `y_test` and `pred_y` to obtain the confusion matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: You may find [sklearn's classification report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

f_y_test = list(chain.from_iterable(y_test))
f_pred_y = list(chain.from_iterable(pred_y))
```

Comment: Please add more details of how this reply applies to the question.